# Removing items from a list if they don't contain a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of URLs, and want to remove any that do not contain imgur or youtube.

```
somelist = ['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'imgur.com/9utwj.gif', 'youtube.com/ofskdofk', 'yahoo.com']
approved = ['imgur','youtube']

for app in approved:
    matching = [s for s in somelist if app in s]
    for match in matching:
        somelist.remove(match)
print somelist
```

This returns

```
['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'yahoo.com']
```

So logically, I felt that if I changed this to be NOT in s....

```
matching = [s for s in somelist if app not in s]
```

it would remove everything that doesn't contain an approved URL. However, it returns nothing.

Comment: `mymaliciousite.com/evilpage?ignoreme=youtube+imgur`...

Answer (score 10):

You can use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to see if any string in approved is in each url from somelist:

```
somelist = ['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'imgur.com/9utwj.gif', 'youtube.com/ofskdofk', 'yahoo.com']
approved = ['imgur','youtube']


somelist[:] = [url for url in somelist if any(sub in url for sub in approved)]

print(somelist)
['imgur.com/9utwj.gif', 'youtube.com/ofskdofk']
```

`any` will short circuit on the first match, if you had urls that had more than one substring it will still only add the url once.

The `somelist[:]` just means we change the original list/object using the efficiency of a list comp instead of using a regular for loop with `list.remove.`

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you think the slice operator is giving you here.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you are using `somelist[:]` on the left side of the assignment only to get the side-effect (not explicitly) requested in the question - to change the original list. Normally in Python (if the side-effect is not needed) we would simply assign to `somelist` and the garbage collector would remove the original list if it is not referenced anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For minimal changes to the version of your code that works, why not just take the property that you know is good (finding matches and doing something with them), and change what's being done, i.e., append to a new list instead of removing from the old?  Viz.:

```
newlist = []
for app in approved:
    matching = [s for s in somelist if app in s]
    for match in matching:
        newlist.append(match)
print newlist
```

and then when you want to do fancier things, you can turn this into a function with no side effects...

[edit: I see this is basically the same method as the answer above, which crossed wires with mine!  go vote that one up.  :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Concisely:

```
results = [url for url in somelist for app in approved if app in url]
```

Comment: This potentially duplicates entries (i.e. if two apps are in a url).

Answer (score 0):

This one is with OR and without the second FOR-loop. The same result.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

somelist = ['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'imgur.com/9utwj.gif', 'youtube.com/ofskdofk', 'yahoo.com']
approved = ['imgur','youtube']

L=[]

for s in somelist:
        if s.find('imgur') != -1 or s.find('youtube') != -1:
            L.append(s)

somelist=L

print somelist
```

Output

```
['imgur.com/9utwj.gif', 'youtube.com/ofskdofk']
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

somelist = ['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'imgur.com/9utwj.gif', 'youtube.com/ofskdofk', 'yahoo.com']
approved = ['imgur','youtube']

L=[]

for s in somelist:
    for app in approved:
        if s.find(app) != -1:
            L.append(s)

somelist=L

print somelist
```

Output

```
['imgur.com/9utwj.gif', 'youtube.com/ofskdofk']
```

Comment: Sure, this works, but it couldn't be farther from Pythonic idiom.

Comment: You are creating references with lists which is rarely a good idea, you will also add the same url twice if both substrings appear

Comment: Yah, this needs short circuiting logic to avoid duplicates. Add a break following the append.

Comment: You can't get duplicates if you can count to two. Each "s" from "somelist" is checked only twice. It can contain either "imgur" or "youtube". You could put just an if condition with an OR operator to get the same result. I made another for-loop just because "approved" can be expanded to infinity. But you will definitely get duplicates if "somelist" contains ones. I made another post below to illustrate how OR works.

Comment: I can manage to count to 2 alright, that is how I know when you have an inner loop that has two iterations and the string `s` you are checking contains both substrings then it will get added twice.

Comment: So what? Just don't put the same substring in two different places and you won't have to search for it twice.